# select distinct values from columns col1 and 2 and keep order by col3

Tags: database, oracle

I'm sorry if this is question is noobish - I'm new to SQL however I did already some googling and found no solution suitable (or none that I could understand due to limited SQL knowledge)

I'm trying to get the distinct values of pairs `Col1` and `Col2`  sorted by `Col3`, this seems easy done by:

```
select distinct Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table order by Col3 desc
```

I also need to get rid of `Col3` and also get rir of duplicated ofCol1 and Col2 pairs and keep them sorted by `Col3`, but when try to select distinct on a sub-query the order is changed.

```
select distinct Col1, Col2 from (select distinct Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table order by Col3)
```

Is there a way around this? 
How can I get the distinct values of `Col1`, `Col2` but sorted by `Col3`?

Here is some of data that I work on:

```
COL1        COL2    COL3
HOST_01     XR1     6387900000000
HOST_01     XR1     6280600000000
HOST_01     XR1     6237600000000
HOST_01     XR1     6194700000000
HOST_01     XR1     6080200000000
HOST_01     XR1     6058800000000
HOST_02     XR2     1134300000000
HOST_02     XR2     1132200000000
HOST_02     XR2     1130600000000
HOST_02     XR2     1128600000000
HOST_02     XR2     1128000000000
HOST_02     XR2     1121900000000
HOST_06     YR1     1120100000000
HOST_02     XR2     1113500000000
HOST_06     YR1     1072100000000
HOST_06     YR1     1050600000000
HOST_10     IT0     1050600000000
HOST_06     YR1     979010000000
HOST_06     YR1     971750000000
HOST_06     YR1     952110000000
HOST_06     YR1     930640000000
HOST_06     YR1     926500000000
HOST_10     IT0     926500000000
HOST_06     YR1     922210000000
```

I would need the output to look like:

```
COL1     COL2
HOST_01  XR1
HOST_02  XR2
HOST_06  YR1
HOST_10  IT0
HOST_06  YR1
HOST_10  IT0
```

Comment: You can remove the outer distinct from your second query (`select col1,col2 from (subquery...)`), but what's the problem with having col3 in the output?

Comment: Hi Joe, the problem with col3 Is that there are repetitions of col1 and col2 values. I need to get rid of those and keep it sorted per col3 (this is why I tried to use double distinct, but the second one re-sorts the data)

Comment: So there are multiple values of COL3 for some combinations of COL1/COL2?  If so, how do you know which value of COL3 to sort by?

Comment: There are multiple values of col1 & col2 per col3, col3 contains numbers. I need to sort rows by col3. And then get distinct rows of col1, col2 keeping things in order by col3...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then putting a max() around COL3 and grouping by COL1/COL2 will allow you to order by COL3 while still returning the distinct COL1/COL2 combinations.  If I'm not understanding you, then please update your question with some sample data.

Comment: I have used max() also but it only return one row with biggest col3 value (and corespomding col1 col2). I'm not sure how to use group by in this query... Could you please elaborate, Joe?

Comment: It would really help if you would post sample data; if you have more than one COL3 for combinations of COL1/COL2, then I don't understand how you expect the sorting to work.

Comment: Ok I'll add the data as soon as posible...

Comment: @Joe I have added the data except as required... As the Col3 sum-s up the data processed by eatch instance on eatch host there is little possibility that the Col3 values will be same for 2x different Col1 & Col2 combinations.

Comment: Ok, that helps.  But I'm still wondering what you expect to see for output.  For HOST_01/XR1 there are six values for col3; so how do you expect it to be sorted?  If you could add in your expected output, that would be very helpful.  **EDIT** I created a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e02c/3/0) showing it sorted by the sum of col3, but I'm not sure yet that that is what you want.

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for your input but the problem is I would need to see the single instance of each col1 and col2 value so the output would be: "HOST_01, XR1" as row one, "HOST_02, XR2" for row 2, "HOST_06, YR1". as if it would be ordered by the col3, but the duplicates are the problem :(

Comment: Yes, I understand.  But the question is -- if you have multiple col3 values for HOST_01/XR1, how do you decide WHICH col3 value to sort by?

Comment: @Joe I have gone trough the data from col3 - there are no duplicates at the moment.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page.  Can you please illustrate what you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Joe as per your request I have edited the question, sorry If I'm not clear enough.

Comment: That's not a distinct list -- HOST_06/YR1 and HOST_10/IT0 are duplicated.

Comment: ah didn't notice that before, in this case It's not relevant which one of these 2 comes first

Comment: Ok, so if we exclude the bottom two, then the remainder is simply sorted by COL1, then COl2.  I don't see how COL3 affects the sort order.

Comment: yes, exactly But IF I use select distinct it will destroy the current order and this is crucial to keep things in this particular order.

Comment: Ok, so would `select col1,col2 from table order by 1,2` not do it?

Comment: I need to keep the order of col1&2 as is now displayed, just get the duplicates out from col1&2.

Comment: But what is determining the current order?  It does not appear to be based on col3 at all.

Comment: actually the example data is ordered by col3 with 'select distinct Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table order by Col3'

Comment: ups - should be: 
select distinct Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table order by Col3 desc

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that.  I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
select distinct Col1, Col2 from Table order by Col3
```

You do not need to select the column used for ordering.

Comment: You do with `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

We've had quite a long discussion in the comments, and I'm still not 100% clear on what you need, but I'm hopeful that one of these two options will get you close.

The first query will produce what you seem to be asking for -- the original list without the replicated rows.  However, it's different from your sample output, in that there are out-of-order values.  For example:

```
HOST_06     YR1     1120100000000
HOST_02     XR2     1113500000000
HOST_06     YR1     1072100000000
```

Here's the SQL:

```
select 
  col1,col2
from 
(
  select 
    col1,col2,col3,
    lag(col1,1,0) over(order by col3 desc) last_col1,
    lag(col2,1,0) over(order by col3 desc) last_col2,
    rownum row_num
  from 
    test
) 
where
  col1 != last_col1 or col2 != last_col2
order by 
  row_num
```

The output:

```
HOST_01     XR1
HOST_02     XR2
HOST_06     YR1
HOST_02     XR2
HOST_06     YR1
HOST_10     IT0
HOST_06     YR1
HOST_10     IT0
HOST_06     YR1
```

And the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d620/10/0)

The second option simply uses the max(col3) per col1/col2.  This closely matches your sample output, with the duplicated rows removed.

The SQL

```
select
  col1,col2
from
(
  select col1,col2,max(col3)
  from test
  group by col1,col2
  order by 3 desc
)
```

The output:

```
HOST_01     XR1
HOST_02     XR2
HOST_06     YR1
HOST_10     IT0
```

And the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d620/14)

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for your input, but this is also not the case. However I have found another way to get the information I need. Thank you for yout time!